# Android circular border around circular image

Tags: android, border, android-bitmap

I do this to get a circular `ImageView`, how can I add a circle border around it like this picture:

[image: Screenshot of expected result]

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage,int width) {
    int targetWidth = width;
    int targetHeight = width;
    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, 
            targetHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.addCircle(((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2,
            ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2,
            (Math.min(((float) targetWidth), 
            ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),
            Path.Direction.CCW);
    canvas.clipPath(path);
    Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;
    canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, 
            new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(),
            sourceBitmap.getHeight()), 
            new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), null);
    return targetBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very interesting post about this feature:
http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/
It is written by Romain Guy (ex android team at Google).

You can use something like this:
This example create a circular bitmap, with around a white stroke.
You can change it, adding a white stroke with a black line.

```
public class CircleDrawable extends Drawable {

    private final BitmapShader mBitmapShader;
    private final Paint mPaint;
    private Paint mWhitePaint;
    int circleCenterX;
    int circleCenterY;
    int mRadus;
    private boolean mUseStroke = false;
    private int mStrokePadding = 0;

    public CircleDrawable(Bitmap bitmap) {

        mBitmapShader = new BitmapShader(bitmap,
                Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setShader(mBitmapShader);

    }

    public CircleDrawable(Bitmap bitmap, boolean mUseStroke) {
        this(bitmap);

        if (mUseStroke) {
            this.mUseStroke = true;
            mStrokePadding = 4;
            mWhitePaint = new Paint();
            mWhitePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
            mWhitePaint.setStrokeWidth(0.75f);
            mWhitePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
        circleCenterX = bounds.width() / 2;
        circleCenterY = bounds.height() / 2;

        if (bounds.width() >= bounds.height())
            mRadus = bounds.width() / 2;
        else
            mRadus = bounds.height() / 2;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mUseStroke) {
            canvas.drawCircle(circleCenterX, circleCenterY, mRadus, mWhitePaint);
        }
        canvas.drawCircle(circleCenterX, circleCenterY, mRadus - mStrokePadding, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        mPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }

    public boolean ismUseStroke() {
        return mUseStroke;
    }

    public void setmUseStroke(boolean mUseStroke) {
        this.mUseStroke = mUseStroke;
    }

}
```